# react.js axios rounding up values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, h2

**react.js axios is rounding up Long values, how this can be resolved ?**

As I have previously checked all my api's via postman, I can surely tell you that my apis are just fine.

Now the problem is when I send I Long value to react.js client, it rounds up the value, so when I try to retrieve it back it creates problem.

Here is a snap:

[image]

- **Second value is what I sent**
- **First value is what I got in client**

Server - *Spring Boot with h2,jpa*

Comment: That's way bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` value. You need to send it as a string from server side

Comment: Also, please go through [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Just add transformResponse to your axios config and use json-big-int to turn the int into a big-int

`const config = {
  transformResponse: [(data: any) => JSONbig.parse(data)],
};
const { data } = await axios.get(url, config);`

Comment: Addition to my comment from above: import json-bigint like this `const JSONbig = require("json-bigint")({ useNativeBigInt: true });` That way the big int will be stored as a js native big int.